# Classical guitar technique problems with leaning ring finger

Tags: guitar, technique, classical-guitar, fingerstyle-guitar

I've recently started guitar lessons with a local tutor. He's lent me his classical guitar — and ok I'm only two or three days in — but my ring finger on my left fret hand leans towards the middle finger. I'm struggling to play the homework my tutor gave me. He told me to learn the chromatic scale and a few chords such as D and e minor. I'm getting better at reading music, and getting the hang of it, but I'm not sure my bent fingers will help at all. Or I am being impatient with the progress and my bent finger. Will there be improvement, and will I be able to play a few chords? Am I running before I can walk?

Comment: If the proposed duplicate post doesn't answer you question, consider posting a picture to more clearly demonstrate the problem you've encountered.

Comment: You may also find helpful information in [Do I have a problem in my ring finger?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/10237/70803) and [Is fingers pointing towards each other a problem when fretting a guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/88142/70803).